# Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) css

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have been trying to find out how to add PHP from ACF to style some text in CSS. Using: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/color-picker/

```
.special-color {
    background-color: <?php the_field('color'); ?>;
}
```

Comment: ...and what is it that you CAN'T figure out?

Comment: It doesnt add the php css portion in the inspector.

Comment: Where have you added the code above?

Comment: in my child theme css

Comment: That's not PHP mate...here I'll post an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo php into workable CSS, you'll have to include the CSS in the php sections of the site (or something more advanced, probably using functions.php). This will work if you simply add:

```
<style>
 .special-color {
  background-color: <?php the_field('color'); ?>;
 }
</style>
```

..to (say) your single.php file within the loop.

As an aside, I don't think this would be a viable way to alter site colours (if that's what you are trying to do?), but more as a way of (say) specifying a particular color for a title of one post.

Then you might think of including the style INLINE (pseudo code):

```
<h1 style="color: <?php the_field('color'); ?>">Post title</h1>
```

Comment: How i worked it out if anyone else needs it. I added a php to shortcode plugin. Created a shortcode with `<?php the_field('color'); ?>` Added the <h1 style="color:[php snippet=2]">Text Here</h1> my template. Now I can dynamically change the color of anything on template with ACFs.

Answer (score 0):

Simply I get the "advanced custom field" value (which is custom_color for an element) of the current post, and then change the element's color using JQuery.

So I created a new js file (custom_css.js) in the child theme with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    console.log(css.custom_color);
    // add dynamic css to the elements

});
```

Then here is the code in functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_css');
/* Get position details */
function custom_css() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_css.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('custom_css', 'css', array(
        'admin_url'     => admin_url(),
        'custom_color'  => get_field('custom_color', get_queried_object_id() )
    ));

}
```